# php: symbol lookup error: php: undefined symbol: rl_on_new_line while using phalcon dev tool

Tags: php, centos, phalcon

I tried installing phalcon dev tool and when using

$phalcon command I got

Php: symbol lookup error: Php: undefined symbol: rl_on_new_line

Comment: We need to see some code.

Comment: You're running a outdated version of libedit on your system.

Comment: Package libedit-20090923-3.0_1.el5.rf.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

@Ohgodwhy libedit seems fine!!

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea Please let me know what exactly you like to know!!

Comment: Thanks, @Ohgodwhy I updated and it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running an outdated version of **libedit** on My system.

- I have removed old version,
- Reinstall using new version

Updating it clear that error:

```
$ phalcon
```

> Php: symbol lookup error: Php: undefined symbol: rl_on_new_line